# How to fix the following SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I created a database with 6 tables (6 entities), among which 3 tables are called "Sessions", "Reviews", and "Persons". Their specifications are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions(
s_tutorID VARCHAR(6),
startTime DATETIME,
location VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
language VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
s_studentID VARCHAR(6),
paidOrNot BINARY(1) NOT NULL, 
reviewedOrNot BINARY(1), 
INDEX (startTime),
INDEX (language),
PRIMARY KEY (s_tutorID, startTime),
FOREIGN KEY (s_tutorID) REFERENCES TutorsAddedLanguage(tutorID) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY (s_studentID) REFERENCES StudentsAddedPayment(studentID) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT s_tutorIDform CHECK (s_tutorID REGEXP '^[a-z]{2}\d{4}$' > 0),
CONSTRAINT s_studentIDform CHECK (s_studentID REGEXP '^[a-z]{2}\d{4}$' > 0));


CREATE TABLE Persons(
ID VARCHAR(6),
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
photo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
department VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
graduatingYear YEAR(4) NOT NULL,
gender BINARY(1) NOT NULL,
selfIntro VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
CONSTRAINT IDform CHECK (ID REGEXP '^[a-z]{2}\d{4}$' > 0));

CREATE TABLE Reviews(
r_tutorID VARCHAR(6),
r_sessionStartTime DATETIME,
r_studentID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
r_sessionLanguage VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
-- score DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
score INT NOT NULL,
givenTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
comments VARCHAR(1000),
PRIMARY KEY (r_tutorID, r_sessionStartTime),
FOREIGN KEY (r_tutorID) REFERENCES Sessions(s_tutorID),-- ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (r_studentID) REFERENCES Sessions(s_studentID),-- ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (r_sessionStartTime) REFERENCES Sessions(startTime),-- ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (r_sessionLanguage) REFERENCES Sessions(language),
CONSTRAINT r_studentIDform CHECK (r_studentID REGEXP '^[a-z]{2}\d{4}$' > 0),
CONSTRAINT r_tutorIDform CHECK (r_tutorID REGEXP '^[a-z]{2}\d{4}$' > 0),
CONSTRAINT scoreform CHECK (score <= 5 AND score >= 0));
```

Then, I inserted some fake data into each table, making sure that all the logic between each data entry is correct.

Now, I want to write a query that select all the sessions on 2016-01-03, and the sessions's language is ENG (English), and Sessions.paidOrNot = '0'. The output should be a table with the following columns: date, starttime, endtime, location, Tutor_name, Tutor_email.

I wrote the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%d %b %Y') AS date,      
DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%h:%i %p') AS starttime,    
DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'%h:%i %p') AS endtime, 
S.location, 
P.name AS Tutor_name, 
CONCAT(P.ID, '@gmail.com') AS Tutor_email 
FROM Sessions S, Persons P 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-01-03' 
AND S.paidOrNot = '0' 
AND S.s_tutorID = P.ID 
AND S.language = 'ENG' 
ORDER BY S.startTime ASC;
```

The output table is as follows:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
| date        | starttime | endtime  | location | Tutor_name       | Tutor_email         |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
| 03 Jan 2016 | 09:00 AM  | 09:30 AM | AlexHall   | Mike Connolly    | mc9514@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 09:30 AM  | 10:00 AM | Winson     | Choko Cahill     | cc6624@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 10:00 AM  | 10:30 AM | Turner   | Mike Connolly    | mc9514@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 02:00 PM  | 02:30 PM | GrandHall   | Milenka Caterini | mc1894@gmail.com |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

Now, I want to add another column to the above query result table, a column called "Average_Review_Score", that takes the average value of Reviews.score for this tuple's Tutor_name in the Reviews table, and the scores have to be scores on this same language (ENG).

For example, the Reviews table looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from Reviews order by r_tutorID;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| r_tutorID | r_sessionStartTime  | r_studentID | r_sessionLanguage | score | givenTime           | comments                                                                                |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ah0133     | 2015-10-02 15:00:00 | jc3323       | JAP               |     4 | 2015-10-02 18:55:33 | oh yeah!                                                                                |
| ah0133     | 2015-10-08 12:00:00 | mc9514       | JAP               |     4 | 2015-10-10 10:59:39 | NULL                                                                                    |
| cc6624     | 2015-09-13 20:00:00 | ah0133       | ENG               |     4 | 2015-10-01 06:38:52 | Choko did a good job helping me with English writing. But he was late for 10 minutes... |
| cc6624     | 2015-10-08 13:00:00 | ah0133       | ENG               |     0 | 2015-10-09 18:49:29 | The tutor did not show up at all                                                        |
| jc3323     | 2015-10-08 12:00:00 | as3699       | SPA               |     3 | 2015-10-08 12:32:41 | NULL                                                                                    |
| jc3323     | 2015-10-08 13:00:00 | es4937       | SPA               |     1 | 2015-10-09 16:01:17 | bad                                                                                     |
| mc1894     | 2015-10-01 12:00:00 | cc6624       | SPA               |     4 | 2015-10-01 12:35:08 | Good session, but I dont think its really helpful to improve my Spanish class grade!    |
| mc1894     | 2015-10-01 13:00:00 | as3699       | SPA               |     3 | 2015-10-02 12:00:00 | fair                                                                                    |
| mc9514     | 2015-10-02 11:30:00 | ep6229       | ENG               |     5 | 2015-11-04 14:22:01 | NULL                                                                                    |
| mc9514     | 2015-10-03 10:00:00 | as3699       | SPA               |     5 | 2015-10-03 11:13:31 | oh my god                                                                               |
| mc9514     | 2015-10-03 12:00:00 | cc6624       | LAT               |     3 | 2015-10-04 23:45:17 | enough                                                                                  |
| mc9514     | 2015-11-09 19:30:00 | pd0039       | ENG               |     2 | 2015-11-09 22:49:13 | not vey helpful                                                                         |
| pd0039     | 2015-10-09 12:00:00 | nm3384       | FRE               |     3 | 2015-10-11 03:14:36 | NULL                                                                                    |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

The previous SQL query gives me 4 sessions, as listed above and I just put it here again:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
| date        | starttime | endtime  | location | Tutor_name       | Tutor_email         |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
| 03 Jan 2016 | 09:00 AM  | 09:30 AM | AlexHall   | Mike Connolly    | mc9514@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 09:30 AM  | 10:00 AM | MidCafe     | Choko Cahill     | cc6624@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 10:00 AM  | 10:30 AM | Turner   | Mike Connolly    | mc9514@gmail.com |
| 03 Jan 2016 | 02:00 PM  | 02:30 PM | GrandHall   | Milenka Caterini | mc1894@gmail.com |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------+---------------------+
```

So now, I want to add a column "Average_Review_Score". For example, for the first ENG session taught by Mike Connolly (ID: mc9514), the value of "Average_Review_Score" should be (5+2)/2 = 3.5, because in the Reviews table as shown above, this tutor Mike Connolly (ID: mc9514) has received 4 reviews so far, and among the 4 reviews, 2 of them are reviews about "ENG" (Reviews.r_sessionLanguage): one review gets a score of 5, the other review has a score of 2. Similarly we want to find the value of "Average_Review_Score" for all the other two tutors: Choko Cahill (ID: cc6624) and Milenka Caterini (ID: mc1894).

To achieve this purpose, I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%d %b %Y') AS date,      
DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%h:%i %p') AS starttime,    
DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'%h:%i %p') AS endtime, 
S.location, 
P.name AS Tutor_name, 
CONCAT(P.ID, '@gmail.com') AS Tutor_email, 
AVG(R.score) AS Average_Review_Score
FROM Sessions S, Persons P, Reviews R
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-01-03' 
AND S.paidOrNot = '0' 
AND S.s_tutorID = P.ID 
AND S.language = 'ENG' 
AND R.r_tutorID = S.s_tutorID 
AND R.r_sessionLanguage = S.language
ORDER BY S.startTime ASC;
```

However, this query right above gives me only one session:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+
| date        | starttime | endtime  | location | Tutor_name   | Tutor_email      | Average_Review_Score |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+
| 03 Jan 2016 | 09:30 AM  | 10:00 AM |  MidCafe    | Choko Cahill | cc6624@gmail.com |               3.0000 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+--------------+------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

How should I write this query then? What's wrong here?

Comment: CONCAT is likely doing some grouping. Group by a unique value such as an id and see if that helps.

Comment: You _really_ need to stick to one convention with your table/column names. Mixed case; underscores used some times, other times not; swapping between camelCase and snake_case…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining a portion of your existing query, but formatted to highlight some suggested changes:

```
...
FROM Sessions S
   , Persons P
   , Reviews R
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-01-03'
      AND S.paidOrNot = '0'
      AND S.s_tutorID = P.ID <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< join (2 tables S & P)
      AND S.language = 'ENG'
      AND R.r_tutorID = S.s_tutorID  <<<<<<<< join (2 tables R & S)
      AND R.r_sessionLanguage = S.language << join (2 tables R & S)
```

I suggest you stop using commas in the FROM clause. This helps you adopt a more robust method of defining joins and as an added bonus the where clause gets simplified.

I also suggest you do NOT use the function DATE_FORMAT() in the where clause. It is more efficient to leave the data unchanged. Instead use a combination of >= with < to filter for all values of a timestamp within the day.

```
...
FROM Sessions S
      INNER JOIN Persons P ON S.s_tutorID = P.ID
      INNER JOIN Reviews R ON R.r_tutorID = S.s_tutorID AND R.r_sessionLanguage = S.language
WHERE S.startTime >= '2016-01-03'
      AND S.startTime < '2016-01-04'
      AND S.paidOrNot = '0'
      AND S.language = 'ENG'
```

Your previous result of a single row indicates that an INNER JOIN is too restrictive so using an LEFT OUTER JOIN instead may be required. Then a GROUP BY clause is needed which should include there "non-aggregating" columns of the select clause [those columns without functions like SUM() COUNT() AVG()]

```
SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime, '%d %b %Y') AS date
    , DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime, '%h:%i %p') AS starttime
    , DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE, '%h:%i %p') AS endtime
    , S.location
    , P.NAME AS Tutor_name
    , CONCAT (P.ID, '@gmail.com') AS Tutor_email
    , AVG (R.score) AS Average_Review_Score
FROM Sessions S
      INNER JOIN Persons P ON S.s_tutorID = P.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Reviews R ON R.r_tutorID = S.s_tutorID AND R.r_sessionLanguage = S.language
WHERE S.startTime >= '2016-01-03'
      AND S.startTime < '2016-01-04'
      AND S.paidOrNot = '0'
      AND S.language = 'ENG'
GROUP BY
      DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime, '%d %b %Y')
    , DATE_FORMAT(S.startTime, '%h:%i %p')
    , S.location
    , P.NAME
    , P.ID
ORDER BY
      S.startTime ASC;
```

Comment: Wow this is so helpful! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Yeah, I do need to make sure that I use left outer join instead, and use the GROUP BY well.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use "join" to join your tables, then use "group by" to create aggregation.
SELECT ..., 
AVG(R.score) AS Average_Review_Score
FROM Sessions S
inner join Persons P on S.s_tutorID = P.ID
left join Reviews R on R.r_tutorID = S.s_tutorID AND R.r_sessionLanguage = S.language
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ....
ORDER BY S.startTime ASC;

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now I've figured it out with GROUP BY :)